# Is it possible to create a Windows Service through Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

In my visual studio code project, I have generated an `.exe` file for the project and I'm trying create make my `.exe` as Windows Service.

From [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3990/Simple-Windows-Service-Sample) and [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8a67c0/create-and-install-windows-service-step-by-step-in-C-Sharp/), if I'm not mistaken, these solutions look like done by using Visual Studio instead of Visual Studio Code. Is it possible to create a Window Service through Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cant,

> **Visual Studio Code** is a code editor redefined and optimized for
>   building and debugging modern web and cloud applications. Visual
>   Studio Code is free and available on your favorite platform - Linux,
>   Mac OSX, and Windows.

It has no concept of an **Windows Service**

If you wish to create a Windows service you will have to use Visual Studio or something that can compile standard .net Windows application

---

**Great comment from Ben Voigt**

> You're correct that Visual Studio Code doesn't have a concept of a
>   service, but that's because it is an editor not a compiler. The same
>   C# compiler installed as part of the .NET runtime, can build Windows
>   Services. And you can edit the windows service code in VS Code

Comment: So if I wish to create a Window Service then I have to use Visual Studio 2017 or other application?

Comment: You're correct that Visual Studio Code doesn't have a concept of a service, but that's because it is an editor not a compiler.  The same C# compiler installed as part of the .NET runtime, can build Windows Services.  And you can edit the windows service code in VS Code.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for that, i updated the answer to include these wise words

Answer (score 0):

Although this is quite an old answer I want to revive it because it pops up in a Google search as one of the first hits and the accepted answer is a bit misleading.

You don't need Visual Studio as Ben Voigt wrote. Visual Studio Code is just fine, but neither VS Code nor the .NET Package have build in projects for a windows service. This does not mean you cannot use VS Code for this. You can check available solutions with, maybe in the future there will be project template:

```
dotnet new list
```

As of now you will have to create the files for yourself, just create a new, empty project in VS Code and add the files and classes needed for a windows service. With the above command you will see an empty project for .NET Core  is created by:

```
dotnet new web
```

In this project you will have to create the classes needed for the compilation of a windows service.

The search terms "c# windows service skeleton" will give you solutions. For example the code project site: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14353/Creating-a-Basic-Windows-Service-in-C