# .NET Framework not found when creating Windows Service using VS Code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode. How can I create a window services using VS code? While running a project it is giving the problem that ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" was not found."

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Check out [this](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2782) issue on the VS Code Github. It seems like you don't have .NET Framework version 4.6.1 installed on your computer, can you double check? Also, what's wrong with full fat VS? The Community edition is also free for an unlimited amount of time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create a Windows Service through Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48514358/is-it-possible-to-create-a-windows-service-through-visual-studio-code)

Comment: @Arif not really a duplicate of that question. OP probably just misinterpreted the error message. His question is about him getting an error message when he runs the project and how to fix it. The title is very misleading. Should still be flagged, but as "Unclear what your asking" instead of duplicate

Comment: @MindSwipe feel free to alter the title if you see a misleading one like this.

Comment: @MindSwipe Question title has changed. Now its OK.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I tried, but eventually gave up as I don't fully understand OP's question (hence the "Unclear what you're asking" flag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the .NET framework dlls. I recommend you use visual studio community 2017 for this

Comment: I cannot use any other Visual studio version . Only i can use is Visual studio code.

Comment: @Mrityunjay ok that's fine but you may have a hard time with it.

Comment: @Mrityunjay Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio (be it Community, Pro or Enterprise) are not related whatsoever. VS Code is made to be a fast and extensible text editor, while Visual Studio is a full fledge IDE with support for multiple languages (most but not all running on .NET). So if you're developing a larger or more complex application I strongly recommend using Visual Studio. And, do you want to tell us why you can't use Visual Studio?

Comment: @MindSwipe I imagine probably because he is on Mac or Linux. And I think they call visual studio "Visual Studio IDE" now to differentiate it from visual studio code

Comment: @tomerzeitune so, he's developing a **Windows** Service on Mac or Linux? And huh, you're right, it's now called "Visual Studio IDE"

Comment: @MindSwipe yep some people don't use windows but still want to use Microsoft .NET

Comment: @tomerzeitune do you know what a **[Windows Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service)** is? Developing a Windows Service on anything other than Windows is an absolute pain, because for every manual test that you want to do you have to run it on a Windows machine. And i understand people want to use .NET on other platforms than Windows, that's why I'm glad the .NET Core exists and also use it almost daily.

Comment: @MindSwipe ok , what does it has to do with the question ?   OP needs to use visual studio code.

Comment: @tomerzeitune nothing, I just asked OP why he's using VS Code and you answered it in a way that made no sense