# Windows Service Event Order

Tags: c#, service

I'm trying to make a service for my exe for the first time using C#. I've managed to get it running and put in some event logs. I'm not sure exactly what calls what and when though. It looks like OnStart, Main, and MyNewService.MyNewService all get called. But Main (in another class) gets called in Parallel as OnStart? I assumed OnStart would happen before everything else. Where should I initialize the event source? Arguments still go to Main, right?

Is there a way to access the console read out for debugging purposes. I want to talk to the service from another program and even when it says Running, I don't get a response on my named pipeline.

Comment: It looks like it runs Main, then MyNewService (not sure what to call this part), and then OnStart. If OnStart runs last, what's the point?

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Tutorial: Create a Windows service app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/73806343/10024425 (VB.NET, but shows how to use [log4Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/log4net/) with a service).

Comment: Is InitializeComponent supposed to be built in? All the examples have that, none explain it, and my compiler doesn't like it.
user- I have read through that. I'm using VSCode but took some of that code as my starting point.

Comment: So it looks like Main is first, then when you create the object, the MyNewService is called, then when you tell the service to .Run then onStart gets called. Also, Main should exit? Currently Main waits for a client to connect until forever.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Is it possible to create a Windows Service through Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77472905/10024425)

Comment: _Is InitializeComponent supposed to be built in?_: When using Visual Studio, some of the code is placed in a [partial class.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods) _InitializeComponent()_ is a method that exists in the partial class. Since most tutorials use Visual Studio, you may see if [Visual Studio Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) meets your needs. After getting your code working, you could re-create the project in VS Code and re-factor the code as desired.

Comment: Here are some more resources I found that may be helpful: [Introduction to Windows Service Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/introduction-to-windows-service-applications) and [ServiceBase Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicebase?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256231/discussion-between-furbs-and-user246821).